# django what happends if I bulk_update values which are not changed?

Tags: django, django-models

So I have a function like this, which bulk-updates a many-many field for the parent_object with the given data.
The problem is, not every object given in the `data` parameter will have its position changed. So, What will happen if I tell django to bulk_update values whose positions aren't changed already? Will any exceptions be raised?
For instance, let the list of objects in a many-many field be:

```py
[id=1'blue', id=2'green', id=3'yellow']
```

If I tell django to update these values like

```py
[id=1 update to 'blue', id=2 update to 'purple', id=3 update to 'magenta']
```

Here id=1 is being updated again to it's unchanged value, blue.
will any errors occur?

```py
    def overwrite_object_positions(self, data: list, parent_object):
        """
        Overwrites object-positions, enclosed
        within a transaction. Rolls-back if any error arises.
        """
        transaction.set_autocommit(False)
        try:
            self.get_overwrite_objects(parent_object).bulk_update(data, ['position'])
        except Exception as err:
            transaction.rollback()
            raise ValueError(err)
        else:
            transaction.commit()
        finally:
            transaction.set_autocommit(True)
```

Comment: Why do you think changing value from one to another should result in error

Comment: no, I meant changing a value to the same

Comment: like bulk updating objects with a list,
where the list contains partially unchanged objects.

hope you get what I meant1